# display a bokeh graph in wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, bokeh

can someone post an example to load a bokeh graph into wxpython gui (on Windows 7).

I tried following but wasn't able to see anything loaded. 
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/8YqCZdRBgJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. The bokeh project currently does not have a way to export the graphs as png or jpg files. See https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/538 for more information

Until this issue is formally resolved, you won't be able to show them inside of wxPython unless you use wxPython's webview widget. The webview widget is basically a wrapper around webkit (Linux / Mac) so theoretically you could use that to view a graph generated by bokeh.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had no luck for HTML2_WebView. I used the wxpython demo to quickly try that out. May be I should wait some time until they fix it.

Comment: No problem. There are plenty of other graphing packages you could try, such as matplotlib or plotly or pygal